# Computer not booting after update installed!

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, btrfs

My Ubuntu 16.04 was working fine until it got updated to the "latest version". Now the whole machine is just conked up.

It shows the following :

```
scanning for Btrfs filesystems    
/dev/sda2: clean, 415134/30253056 files, 6128820/120983040 blocks

_ (this line blinks)
```

I cant access GNU GRUB by pressing the *SHIFT* key continuously!

Any idea what went wrong and how to recover the system?

Comment: What do you mean by " it got updated to the "latest version"?

Comment: By Got updated to the latest version means: It downloaded some files for OS update! I presume that would be the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can boot into a live cd or USB and then, make a copy of `/bin/btrfs` to `/sbin/btrfs`.

You may have to reinstall.

I had this problem on a fresh install. After a full reinstall, I ran the following command and it seems to be fine now.

```
sudo ln -s /bin/btrfs /sbin/btrfs
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
```

This also fixes an issue with `apt-btrfs-snapshot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have up voted earlier! Cheers! :)

Comment: @Som92 No prob. This (fix) has been an issue with the past few releases ever since btrfs was moved from /sbin to /bin. There seems to be multiple issues with multiple applications and simply creating this symlink fixes all of them. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-btrfs-snapshot/+bug/1454306 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1483975 We should all create the symlink immediately after installation to prevent issues.

Comment: @Som92 if your problem is solved, consider accepting answer by clicking on the grey tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some more info on the things that you've already tried?

otherwise try to boot into a live cd or usb, this already gives you back some control of your machine.

Try repairing the installed packages from here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure

If that doesn't fix the issue, drop into a shell and check the available log files.

We should be able to move on from there.

\_/>

Comment: In the grub> settings when I gave the "boot" command, It gives me the error " error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd0' , error :failure reading sector 0x0 fro cd 0"

Comment: I had the same issue and it doesn't appear to be related. Cannot even chroot into the partition. It will mount but will not chroot or drop to root shell from grub recovery menu on my server.